# spark logging with spring boot

Tags: apache-spark, spring-boot

I have spring boot application from which jobs are submitted to spark cluster in standalone mode (for testing local mode). When ever the spark context is initialized the log4j configuration specified in Spring are overridden. Is there a way to stop this from happening and tell spark to use the log4j properties from sprint boot application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Arul did you get any solution? I am facing the same issue.